# How to reinstall Snow Leopard on my MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

I've been installing some applications and some things are not working properly. I want to reset my MBP to factory settings. How do I do a clean installation so I can start from scratch?

Comment: I just wanted to say: "Reset to Factory Settings" doesn't really apply to computers, at least not Apple computers (including iPhone/iPad). The concept of resetting to factory settings is only for small(er) devices like the AirPort series, and of course non-computer devices entirely like Tiger handheld gaming systems and a bunch of other cheap stuff. You can load a completely fresh OS, but that's not exactly "Factory Settings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put in the Install DVD.

You can do that with the computer running and run the installer from the disc.

You can also boot directly to the disc by turning off the computer, putting it in, holding down the <kbd>c</kbd> key, and turning the computer on.

Follow the directions, and you'll have a clean install. Your personal files and preferences will be saved, but system files will be replaced.

Comment: None of y files will be deleted o replaced? that's cool but what if i want to completely delete all data as well is there an option?

Comment: If you want to wipe it from scratch, boot from the DVD and use the Disk Utility to format the drive.

Comment: @vcsjones Bingo.

Comment: Say what ??? A clean install also known as "Erase and Install" will wipe the whole system, including your personal files - but an "Archive and Install" will save your personal files, and only re-install the OS X system. Read about the options here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1545

Comment: @Rene read the title of your article. **It doesn't cover Snow Leopard (10.6).** *There is no erase and install option in Snow Leopard*

Comment: @Nathan My bad - but still a "Clean Install" is normally the same as a "Erase and Install", and therefore I wrote what I did, mainly because you wrote that the personal files would be saved/not affected.